# Power BI Custom Table

Tags: powerbi

I am very struck in this issue and I searched everywhere but couldn't found solution.I have requirement to make table which should have image column. As the default table visual in power bi don't have this kind of option.

I have 2 requirements one if I can have image column in table or if some how I can change the row color of table on some condition.

Please find the below image.[image]

Thanks

Comment: The only solution that i know is to create a custom visual to power bi. https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/ . I suggest to see this video to undestand better : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXin5NAPqGE and this tutorial https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools/

Answer (score 1):

You have two very different requirements.  Let's tease them apart:

1) image columns. this is supported in Power BI tables.  You need to go to your data model, ensure there is a image URL field that point to a network accessible image (no authentication) and set it to 'image url'.  The image will load in the table much like what you showed. One image per column is supported. Please note that if you do this, you should scale your images in your storage to be small enough to load quickly.

2) conditional formatting on tables. That's on our backlog. Right now you can build a custom visual like Nicolo suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting is now possible in PowerBI:

[PowerBI-Desktop-Conditional-Table-Formatting](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-conditional-table-formatting/)